# Open a page in other tab

Tags: support

I would like to know if its possible to open a page in an other tab in this case, when I make a right-click with my mouse :

[image]

Like in this case (open the link in an other tab) :

[image]

Because I like to have the principal page to see the questions in real time and answer questions in an other tab, or window sometimes whent I open 50 different tabs lol.

Thank you in advance.

PS : Absolutely no idea for tag so I chose one...

Comment: Right click on a part of the title which is not formatted with mathjax (and then click on "ouvrir le lien dans un nouvel onglet"). If the whole title is formatted with mathjax, yell at the person who wrote the title. If you have a three-button mouse, the middle button usually opens links in a new tab (in most web browsers I know).

Comment: You can `Ctrl+click`, or middle-click (probably, depends on your settings) to open in a new tab if the entire title is MathJax.

Comment: @DanielFischer thats perfect, thank you !

Comment: @NajibIdrissi yell at the person ... or edit the title (I just did).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm a chemist, and I have some good knowlegde in biology, may I poison him? :P

Comment: If you want to "yell" at the poster, you can use [this comment tempate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/9755#9755).